# How to register translate function in app

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3

I got this translate function, in order to use it I have to import it in every component which is quite annoying.

Looks like

```js
import { useI18n } from "vue-i18n";

export default {
   setup() {
       const { t } = useI18n();
       return { t }
   }

 }
```

main.js looks like

```js
import installI18n from "./lang/index";
installI18n(app);
```

lang/index

```
const i18n = createI18n({
  locale: getLocale(),
  legacy: false,
  messages,
});

// export default i18n
export default (app) => {
  app.use(i18n);
};
```

Can I register this somehow in my app, so I dont have to put it in setup every time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [globalInjection](https://vue-i18n.intlify.dev/api/general.html#globalinjection) parameter to enable global injection even in non-legacy (Composition API) mode

```js
const i18n = createI18n({
  locale: getLocale(),
  legacy: false,
  globalInjection: true,
  messages,
});
```

Then you must use functions prefixed with `$` in your templates - see [Implicit with injected properties and functions](https://vue-i18n.intlify.dev/guide/advanced/composition.html#implicit-with-injected-properties-and-functions)

Comment: Seems to work fine in html, but in order to use it in my setup() I need to import it? Because I tried adding $t in my setup function but it says $t is not defined.

Comment: That's how it works in non-legacy mode. Read the link provided - *The `setup` does not allow to see these properties and functions injected into the component*. Everything inside `setup` must be imported as there is no component instance (and `this`).

Answer (score 0):

To use app-wide i18n,

locate translate json files in `locales` folder - `locales/en.json`

```
{
  "key": "value",
}
```

create `i18n.js` file

```js
import Vue from 'vue'
import VueI18n from 'vue-i18n'

Vue.use(VueI18n)

function loadLocaleMessages () {
  const locales = require.context('./locales', true, /[A-Za-z0-9-_,\s]+\.json$/i) // Path to the locales folder
  const messages = {}
  locales.keys().forEach(key => {
    const matched = key.match(/([A-Za-z0-9-_]+)\./i)
    if (matched && matched.length > 1) {
      const locale = matched[1]
      messages[locale] = locales(key)
    }
  })
  return messages
}

export default new VueI18n({
  locale: process.env.VUE_APP_I18N_LOCALE || 'en',
  fallbackLocale: process.env.VUE_APP_I18N_FALLBACK_LOCALE || 'en',
  messages: loadLocaleMessages()
})
```

And then use it as param while creating Vue app - in `app.js`

```
...
import i18n from './i18n'
...
new Vue({
  router,
  store,
  i18n,
  render: h => h(App)
}).$mount('#admin-app')
```

And then use $t() in Vue files. - `index.vue`

```js
<h3>
  {{ $t('key') }}
</h3>
```

Comment: Your code is for Vue 2 and [Vue-in18n version](https://kazupon.github.io/vue-i18n/) for Vue 2 while the question is about Vue 3

Comment: Oh. I think I missed that.